# ola quero fazer um programa, em c, que devolva o minimo multiplo comum entre dois numeros

Tags: c

Este é o código que tenho mas nao me esta a retornar nada. o que estará mal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define nao 0
#define ok 1
int main(){
    int x,y,contador1=1, contador2=1,maior,menor, mmc,estado=nao;
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    if (x<y){
        maior=y;
        menor =x;
    }
    else{
        maior=x;
        menor=y;
    }

    if(x>0 && y>0){
        while(estado==nao){
            while (contador1<=10){
                if (menor*contador1==maior*contador2){
                    estado=ok;
                    mmc=menor*contador1;
                }
                else{
                    contador1++;
                    
                }
            }
            contador2++;    
        } 
    }

    printf("%d\n",mmc);
    return 0;
}
```

obrigado!

Comment: O que acontece se `contador1` ficar maior que 10 e `estado` ainda for igual a `nao`?

Comment: o contador1 nao fica maiior que 10 porque o while so vai ate 10

Comment: Pode chegar até 11 no seu código. Se for igual a 10 ainda entra no laço e é incrementado ficando 11. Faça um teste de mesa para entender melhor o código que escreveu.

Comment: mas a minha pergunta e o porque do codigo nao devolver nada.

Comment: Assim que você conseguir responder o que acontece no seu código quando `contador1` é igual a 11 e `estado` é igual a `nao` você vai entender porque não devolve nada. Se você não entende essa situação bem, significa que não compreendeu 100% o próprio código, por isso sugeri fazer o teste de mesa. Pode ler mais sobre em [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878).

Comment: @user227365 com que valores de x e y você testou? Seu programa chega a finalizar ao entrar com estes valores?