# Percorrendo matriz e somando os valores

Tags: javascript, array

Olá pessoal estava fazendo um desafio do HackerRank, e me deparei com um desafio onde pedia para fazer a soma das diagonais da direita para a esquerda, e da esquerda para direita e por fim retorna a diferença entra as somas, resolvi da seguinte forma mas porém só passou em dois testes:

```
const arr = [
    [11, 2, 4],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 8, -12]
]

function diagonalDifference(arr) {
 var resultado;
  var resultado;
 for(let i = 0; i< 3; i++){
   const a = arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2];
   const b = arr[0][2] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][0];
   return Math.abs(b - a)
 }
}
```

encontrei uma solução melhor que a minha porém gostaria da ajuda de vocês para entender passo a passo como esse código funciona:

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    let diagonal1 = 0;
    let diagonal2 = 0;
    const len = arr.length;

    arr.forEach((elemento, ind) =>{
        diagonal1 += elemento[ind]
        diagonal2 += elemento[len -1 -ind]
    })
    return Math.abs(diagonal1 - diagonal2)
}
```

Comment: Veja [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    [11, 2, 4],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 8, -12]
]

function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    let diagonal1 = 0;
    let diagonal2 = 0;
    const len = arr.length;

    arr.forEach((elemento, ind) =>{
        diagonal1 += elemento[ind]
        diagonal2 += elemento[len -1 -ind]
        console.log(elemento)
    })
    return Math.abs(diagonal1 - diagonal2)
}
diagonalDifference(arr)
```

Observe que  `arr.forEach((elemento, ind)` em cada iteração é retornado uma linha da matriz.

Perceba que os elementos da diagonal principal vao incrementando na no codigo isso representado por `ind`, que começa em 0 e vai até 2.

Enquanto que os elementos da diagonal secundaria vão diminuindo, comecando em 2 e decrementando ate chegar ao 0 no codigo isso é feito com `len -1 -ind`.

A imagem abaixo ajudará no entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito obrigado, eu estava seguindo essa linha de raciocínio, mas ainda não estava muito claro, conseguir entender claramente o comportamento do código