# Como substituir o Len do Python em C

Tags: c

Como fazer isso dar certo? No caso, eu estou tentando usar um "for" para o contador a cada valor inserido no while aumentar em 1 (para calcular a média corretamente). Isso poderia ser resolvido no Python com a função len, mas ela não existe em C[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-Vindo ao Stack Overflow. Por favor, sempre que for fazer uma pergunta coloque o seu código dentro da pergunta, e não uma foto do código.

Comment: Clique [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobrevivência-do-sopt-versão-curta?cb=1), para mais informações.

Comment: Você faz um `while (notas != 0)`, mas a variável `notas` nem foi inicializada com algum valor; você faz o `for` enquanto `cont != notas`, mas `notas` não possui valor; você faz `media` receber `notas + notas`, qual o sentido disso, de duplicar o valor da nota? Enfim, eu até poderia responder com um código que fizesse o que aparentemente precisa, mas para mim ficou claro que você ainda não entendeu o próprio código que escreveu, então eu recomendo que veja o que é um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) e tente aplicá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um macete para calcular o tamanho.

Se o seu vetor for de inteiros, você pode utilizar o seguinte trecho de código para calcular o tamanho.

```
int length = (int) sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```