# Deu o erro "list index out of range" e não entendo o motivo

Tags: python, for

```
notas = [10,5,6,7,8]

for i in range(0,len(notas)+1):
    print(notas[i])
```

Deu o erro:

```
line 4, in <module>
    print(notas[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua lista possui 5 elementos, então `len(notas)` retornará o inteiro 5, sendo a primeira posição 0 e a última 4.

Você definiu um laço de repetição de forma que:

```
for i in range(0,len(notas)+1):
    ...
```

Ou seja, o seu `range` irá percorrer o conjunto de valores `[0, len(notas) + 1[` (conjunto aberto na direita por definição da linguagem). Como o `len` é 5, ficará `[0, 6[`, que tratando de números inteiros será o conjunto `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Ou seja, na última iteração, o `i` valerá 5 e tentará acessar a posição 5 da sua lista, que não existe.

O correto seria sem o `+ 1`:

```
for i in range(0,len(notas)):
    ...
```

Mas melhor que isso, você pode percorrer a lista diretamente sem utilizar a variável de controle `i` e sem depender do tamanho da lista:

```
for nota in notas:
    print(nota)
```

Para facilitar a identificação desses tipos de problemas recomendo a leitura:

- [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)