# Dúvida com o contador no while

Tags: python, while

Analisando esse código que serve para calcular progressão aritimética e que está funcionando corretamente:

```
primeiro_termo = int (input ('Primeiro termo: ')) 
razao = int (input ('Razão: '))
contador = 1
resultado = primeiro_termo
total = 0
a_mais = 10

while a_mais != 0:
    total = total + a_mais
    print ('Resultado = ', end='')
    while contador <= total:
        resultado += razao
        contador += 1
        print (resultado, end=' ')
    a_mais = int (input ('\nQuantos termos a mais você quer mostrar?: '))
print (contador)
print (f'Obrigado por jogar. Você consultou {total} termos.')
```

Nesse caso a variável `contador` não devia continuar somando, a medida que eu fosse atribuindo novos valores a variável `a_mais`?
Isso não impediria a condição `while` de funcionar? Uma vez que o valor agregado na variável `contador` seria maior do que o valor da variável `total`?

O `print` que eu fiz do contador na penúltima linha mostra que ele está somando normalmente, mas ainda assim, a condição `while` é executada como se o `contador` estivesse zerado.

Só para deixar claro, o código está funcionando corretamente, a minha dúvida é entender porque ele funciona, uma vez que no meu entendimento de iniciante a variável `contador` deveria ser zerada para a condição `while` poder ser executada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) já ajudaria a entender melhor. Mas enfim, vamos ver o que acontece:

Supondo que foi digitado `primeiro_termo = 1` e `razao = 2`. As demais variáveis serão:

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| contador | 1 |
| resultado | 1 |
| total | 0 |
| a_mais | 10 |

Como `a_mais` vale `10`, ele entra no `while a_mais != 0`.

A linha `total = total + a_mais` é executada, então temos:

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| contador | 1 |
| resultado | 1 |
| **total** | **10** |
| a_mais | 10 |

Depois ele imprime a mensagem "Resultado = ", e pelos valores acima temos que `contador` é menor que `total` e portanto entra no `while contador <= total`.

Ao executar `resultado += razao` e `contador += 1`, temos:

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| **contador** | **2** |
| **resultado** | **3** |
| total | 10 |
| a_mais | 10 |

Ele imprime o `resultado` (que é `3`), e como `contador` ainda é menor que `total`, ele continua no `while contador <= total`.

Esse processo é repetido várias vezes. Vou pular estas etapas porque será repetitivo - afinal, é um *loop* :-) - mas quando `contador` chegar a `11`, ele sai do `while contador <= total`. Neste ponto, teremos:

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| contador | 11 |
| resultado | 21 |
| total | 10 |
| a_mais | 10 |

Aí você lê novamente um valor para `a_mais`. Vamos supor que agora eu digite `1`. Ou seja, agora `a_mais` será 1 e por isso ele continua no `while a_mais != 0`. Então ele executa a linha `total = total + a_mais`, e aí teremos:

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| contador | 11 |
| resultado | 21 |
| **total** | **11** |
| **a_mais** | **1** |

Repare que `total` foi atualizado, e por isso a condição do `while contador <= total` continua sendo satisfeita. Por isso que ele executa esse `while` novamente. Não tem essa história de "*a condição while é executada como se o contador estivesse zerado*". O `contador` não foi zerado, só que o `total` foi atualizado e por isso a condição do `while` continua válida.

---

Só para constar que esse código não está imprimindo o primeiro termo. No exemplo acima eu digitei `primeiro_termo = 1` e `razao = 2` e o primeiro número impresso é o `3`, mas se o primeiro termo é `1`, então não deveria começar por `1`?

Enfim, entendo que - *provavelmente* - este é um exercício e tal, mas só para deixar registrado, dá para fazer isso usando os recursos da própria linguagem. Se quer uma sequência de números, use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que é feito justamente para isso. Assim você já consegue imprimir e pegar o tamanho mais facilmente (nem precisa mais do contador):

```
primeiro_termo = int(input('Primeiro termo: ')) 
razao = int(input('Razão: '))
quantidade = 10 # quantidade de termos que será impressa
total = 0

while True:
    numeros = range(primeiro_termo, primeiro_termo + quantidade * razao, razao)
    total += len(numeros)
    print(*numeros, sep=' ', end=' ')
    quantidade = int(input('\nQuantos termos a mais você quer mostrar?: \n'))
    if quantidade == 0:
        break # sai do while
    # nova sequência começa do próximo termo (ou seja, o último a ser impresso + a razão da PA)
    primeiro_termo = numeros[-1] + razao

print(f'Obrigado por jogar. Você consultou {total} termos.')
```

Comment: Entendi. Isso mesmo, é apenas um exercício para praticar o while. Realmente, era para começar o primeiro termo com 1, mas não sei como fazer isso também.

Comment: @MarcosFacini Pra começar do 1, basta inverter (somar a razão só depois de imprimir): https://ideone.com/gV3aZs