# desenhar um quadrado com laços de repetição em portugol

Tags: portugol

Olá! estou aprendendo portugol para fins academicos e estou com um probleminha... preciso desenhar um quadrados com asteriscos porém não estou conseguindo desenhar a parte inferior e a direita, está saindo assim[image: saída]
esté é o meu código

```
programa
{
    
    funcao inicio()
    {   
        inteiro contador,asteriscos, coluna = 0
        leia(asteriscos)
            se(asteriscos < 2){
                escreva("*")
            }senao{
                para(contador = 0; contador < asteriscos; contador++){
                    escreva("*")
                    escreva(" ")
            }enquanto(coluna < contador){
                escreva("\n*")
                coluna++
            }
}
}
}
```

deveria estar saindo assim(caso o número fosse 4)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/100416)? Vai ficar mais fácil de entender o que está acontecendo

Comment: pior que sim, estou usando a ferramenta da IDE para fazer, mas mesmo assim estou me matando nesse programinha.

Answer (score 0):

```
programa
{
    funcao desenhaQuadrado(inteiro valor, cadeia simbolo){
        inteiro linha, coluna

        para(linha = 1; linha <= valor; linha++){
            se(linha == 1 ou linha == valor){
                para(coluna = 1; coluna <= valor; coluna++){
                    escreva(simbolo, " ")
                }

            }
            senao{
                para(coluna = 1; coluna <= valor; coluna++){
                    se(coluna == 1 ou coluna == valor){
                        escreva(simbolo, " ")
                    }
                    senao{
                        escreva("  ")
                    }
                }
            }
            escreva("\n")
        }
        
    }
    
    funcao inicio()
    {
        escreva("Desenha quadrado na  tela\n-----------------------\n")
        
        inteiro valor
        cadeia simbolo

        escreva("Qual tamanho seu quadrado terá? ")
        leia(valor)

        escreva("\nQual simbolo usar para desenhar seu quadrado? ")
        leia(simbolo)

        escreva("\nUm quadrado de " + valor + " linha(s) e " + valor + " coluna(s)\n" )

        desenhaQuadrado(valor, simbolo)
    }
}
```

obeservações: O uso da função não é obrigatório. Usei ela aqui pois reaproveitei um exercício que eu ja tinha feito e que usava função. Essa variáveis são passadas na função `desenhaQuadrado(valor, simbolo)`

Vamos à explicação: o usuário determina o tamanho do quadrado através de uma entrada que é salva na variável valor e também determina o símbolo com o qual o quadrado será desenhado, este valor é salvo na variável simbolo do tipo cadeia.

Essa variáveis são passadas na função `desenhaQuadrado(valor, simbolo)`. Dentro da função eu declarei ainda duas variáveis : linha e coluna que vão servir para desenhar o quadrado através de um loop. Para construir o quadrado é necessário ter um loop que controla o número de linhas e dentro desse loop existirá uma outra estrutura de repetição responsável pelas colunas.

Exemplo:
Digamos que usuário digite 3 e o símbolo é *. Será um quadrado de 3 linhas e 3 colunas. Para este exemplo vamos desconsiderar o uso das estruturas de decisão dentro do loop. A função desenhaQuadrado fica assim:

```
funcao desenhaQuadrado(inteiro valor, cadeia simbolo){
        inteiro linha, coluna

        para(linha = 1; linha <= valor; linha++){
            para(coluna = 1; coluna <= valor; coluna++){
                escreva(simbolo, " ")
            }

            escreva("\n")
        }
        
    }
```

**primeira execução**

valor = 3

simbolo = *

começa primeiro loop

linha = 1

começa segundo loop

coluna = 1

output : *

segundo loop

coluna = 2

output = * *

segundo loop

coluna = 3

output = * * *

segundo loop

coluna = 4 (coluna é maior que valor então o loop para)

fim do segundo loop

quebra linha

**fim da primeira execução**

**segunda execução**

valor = 3

simbolo = *

começa primeiro loop

linha = 2

começa segundo loop

coluna = 1

```
output : * * *
         *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 2

```
output = * * *
         * *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 3

```
output = * * *
         * * *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 4 (coluna é maior que valor então o loop para)

fim do segundo loop

quebra linha

**fim da segunda execução**

**terceira execução**

valor = 3

simbolo = *

começa primeiro loop

linha = 3

começa segundo loop

coluna = 1

```
output : * * *
         * * *
         *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 2

```
output = * * *
         * * *
         * *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 3

```
output = * * *
         * * *
         * * *
```

segundo loop

coluna = 4 (coluna é maior que valor então o loop para)

fim do segundo loop

quebra linha

**fim da terceira execução**

**Quarta execução**

valor = 3

simbolo = *

primeiro loop

linha = 4 (loop para pois linha é maior que valor)

**Fim da quarta execução**

```
output = * * *
         * * *
         * * *
```

o uso das estruturas de decisão

essa estruturas são usadas para decidir o seguinte:

**na primeira e última linha :** todas as colunas devem ser preenchidas com o símbolo `*`.

**nas outras linhas:** somente a primeira e a última coluna são prenchidas como símbolo `*`.

Dessa forma o output ficaria :

```
output = * * *
         *   *
         * * *
```

espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -2):

**Consegui resolver o código usando laços de repetição e se.**

Usei as variáveis quadrado, contador, contador2, contador3, espaco, contador4 todas do tipo inteiro.

Escreval(" Qual o tamanho do seu quadrado?")
leia(**quadrado**)

**espaco <- (quadrado*2)-4**

**medida <- quadrado-2**

**para contador de 1 ate quadrado faca**
**escreva**("* ")

```
 se contador = quadrado entao
 escreval(" ")
  para contador2 de 1 ate medida faca
    se contador = quadrado entao
       escreva("* ")
       se quadrado > 2 entao
          para contador4 de 1 ate espaco faca
             escreva(" ")
          fimpara
       fimse
       escreval("* ")
    fimse
     se contador2 = medida entao
        para contador3 de 1 ate quadrado faca
        escreva("* ")
        fimpara
     fimse
 fimse
```

fimpara
fimalgoritmo