# Não entendi a ordem do array retornado nesta recursão

Tags: javascript, recursão

Não estou a conseguir perceber este código, visto que se entrar com o valor de `n = 10` na função countdown devo ter como resposta o seguinte `arr = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`.

Se o unshift adiciona ao início do array não devia obter primeiro o valor de n e depois fazer unshift para os restantes? Ou seja de 1 até 10 em vez de 10 até 1?

Se alguém me conseguir ajudar a perceber agradecia.

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Transferi meus comments para uma resposta por questão até de espaço. Para fazer uma melhor elaboração das próximas dúvidas vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pela ajuda e informação relativa a pergunta mencionada. Obrigado também pela informação do guia de Sobrevivência.

Answer (score 4):

- A função countdown será chamada 11 vezes, com os números de 10 até 0 **antes de ocorrer o primeiro return**;
- Somente quando `n` for `0`, cairá no 1º `if`, que retornará `[]`

  Note:

  - este é o primetro return que ocorre, depois de 10 recursões;
  - até este momento ainda não ocorreu nenhum `unshift`;
- Desta forma, os returns ocorrem com esta sequência de valores:

  ```
  [], [1], [2,1], [3,2,1] ... [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
  ```
- **Após** cada return é que ocorre o unshift, na iteração anterior.

  É por isso que a cadeia crescerà do lado esquerdo do menor número (penultima recursão) até o maior (chamada original).

Em outras palavras, os `unshift`s acontecerão na "volta" das recursões, com `n` na sequência 1 até 10.

### Visualizando

Basicamente o fluxo que ocorre é esse (diminui para n=2 para facilitar):

```
// n = 2                   // n = 1                   // n = 0  

function rec(n) {    ┌─>   function rec(n) {    ┌─>   function rec(n) {
  if (n < 1)         │       if (n < 1)         │       if (n < 1)
    return [];       │         return [];       │  ┌──<   return []; 
  arr = rec(n-1);  >─┘       arr = rec(n-1);  >─┘  │    arr = rec(n-1);
                                                   │
                                                   │
                                                   │
  /* arr = [1] */  <─┐       /* arr = []  */  <────┘ 
  arr.unshift(n);    │       arr.unshift(n);            arr.unshift(n);
  /* arr = [2,1] */  │       /* arr = [1] */
  return arr;        └─<     return arr;                return arr;
}                          }                          }
```

Um caminho para entender como um código trabalha é o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/70) - vale a leitura.

### "Debug de print"

Basicamente é um "teste de mesa automatizado", dando print em lugares estratégicos para acompanhar o fluxo:

```js
function rec(n) {
    console.log('n='+n+' Iniciando');
 
    if (n < 1) {
        console.log('n='+n+' Retornando vazio');
        return [];
    }
 
    console.log('n='+n+' chamando recursão com n-1 ('+(n-1)+')');
    arr = rec(n-1);
 
    console.log('n='+n+' Dando unshift de '+n);
    arr.unshift(n);
 
    console.log('n='+n+' Retornando ['+(arr.toString())+']');
    return arr;
}
 
console.log('Chamando funcao original');
rec(10);
```

Deixei uma versão no IDEONE, talvez facilite leitura: https://ideone.com/wecD0r

Answer (score 0):

utilize "push" no lugar de "unshift", pois ao final da interação eles serão alocados de forma ordenado.

```js
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.push(n);
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(countdown(10))
```