# Programa imprime contagem de 2 a 11 aos invés de 1 a 10

Tags: python, while

Estou usando o `while`, solicito que seja feita de 1 á 10 mas imprime de 2 a 11:

```
def contador (i , f):

    c = i
    While c <= f:
        c += 1
        print(c , end='')

contador (1 ,10)
```

O resultado no print retorna: `2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11`.

[image: erro]

Comment: `c` começa em 1, mas antes de imprimir vc adiciona 1, então o primeiro valor impresso será 2 mesmo. Faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) para entender melhor. Basta fazer `c += 1` depois do `print`, não antes. E não sei se foi erro ao digitar aqui, mas `while` é com "w" minúsculo. Por fim, coloque as mensagens e a saída  como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: E complementando, o problema não é do PyCharm. Ele é só a IDE, a linguagem é Python, e o problema do código aconteceria em qualquer outra IDE (ou até mesmo sem IDE, como por exemplo no bloco de notas), já que é um erro na forma como a linguagem foi usada. Pra entender a diferença entre linguagem e IDE, leia aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/112052

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu problema é bem simples, você está incrementando antes de imprimir o valor, ou seja, quando o número 1 entra no laço, você soma mais 1 e depois imprime e é por isso que está sempre imprimindo um número a mais. Basta inverter as posições assim:

```
c = i
while c <= f:
    print(c , end='')
    c += 1
```

Comment: Existem duas plataformas muito boas uma é o: https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit que é uma plataforma web onde você consegue fazer o debug do seu código e identificar mais facilmente o erro. A outra é o Thonny plataforma desktop para desenvolvimento python que também conta com a opção de debud dentre várias outras que ajudam a entender melhor o código, pois se trata de uma plataforma para aprendizagem. Abraço!