# Verificar se a matriz é simétrica em C

Tags: c, array, matriz

Preciso verificar se uma matriz é simétrica ou não. Consigo imprimir a matriz, mas mesmo ela não sendo simétrica é impressa a frase informando que a matriz é simétrica.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 2

int main(){
    int A[TAM][TAM];

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\nMatriz A: \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++){
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("%3d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++){
            if (A[i][j] == A[j][i]){
                printf("A matriz A e uma matriz simetrica");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você colocou o `printf` dentro do `for`, o que quer dizer que ele pode imprimir a mensagem que é simétrica para qualquer caso em que o elemento da posição `[i][j]` for igual ao elemento da posição `[j][i]` (se encontrar apenas um caso, ele já imprime, independente do restante da matriz).

E isso **sempre** vai acontecer para os elementos da diagonal (pois na diagonal os valores de `i` e `j` são iguais). Faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) no seu código para entender melhor.

A solução é bem simples. Primeiro, você não precisa percorrer a matriz inteira. Uma matriz simétrica é "espelhada": se você considerar que a diagonal é um espelho, os elementos de um lado da diagonal estarão espelhados do outro lado.

Então você só precisa verificar metade da matriz: apenas os elementos de um dos lados da diagonal, comparando com o seu "reflexo" do outro lado, isso já será suficiente. E você pode ignorar a diagonal também, já que na diagonal `i` é igual a `j`, então o elemento da posição `[i][j]` é exatamente o mesmo elemento da posição `[j][i]` (por isso é redundante comparar neste caso).

Não precisa criar a matriz transposta como sugere a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/547816/112052), isso é um desperdício de recursos (pois cria outra matriz à toa), além de precisar iterar por toda a matriz duas vezes (uma para criar a transposta, outra para comparar os elementos).

Ou seja, seria algo assim:

```
int simetrica = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < TAM && simetrica; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if (A[i][j] != A[j][i]){
            simetrica = 0;
            break; // se já achou um diferente, sai do for
        }
    }
}
if (simetrica)
    printf("é simétrica\n");
else printf("não é simétrica\n");
```

Repare que o `i` começa em 1, pois não preciso verificar o primeiro elemento da primeira linha (já que ele faz parte da diagonal). E o `j` só vai até `i`, pois ele só precisa ir até a diagonal.

Percorrer a matriz inteira é desnecessário. Por exemplo, se eu já comparei o elemento da posição (2, 3) com o da posição (3, 2), não preciso verificar a posição (3, 2) de novo. Por isso eu só vou até a diagonal, para evitar comparar duas vezes a mesma coisa.

---

Se quiser, também pode fazer uma função, aí não precisa da variável auxiliar:

```c
int simetrica(int A[TAM][TAM]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < TAM; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (A[i][j] != A[j][i]){
                return 0; // se já achou um diferente, não é simétrica 
            }
        }
    }
    // se comparou tudo e não achou um diferente, é simétrica
    return 1;
}
```

E no `main` basta chamar a função:

```
if (simetrica(A))
    printf("é simétrica\n");
else printf("não é simétrica\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa primeiramente criar a matriz transposta da matriz gerada (transformar as colunas em linhas/transformar as linhas em colunas):

```c
void transpor(int A[TAM][TAM], int trA[TAM][TAM])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
      trA[i][j] = A[j][i];
}
```

Com esta função, a matriz transposta de `A` será armazenada em `trA`. Tendo a matriz transposta, podemos comparar cada elemento da mesma com o elemento correspondente na matriz original:

```c
int ehSimetrica(int A[TAM][TAM])
{
  int trA[TAM][TAM];
  transpor(A, trA);
  for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
      if (A[i][j] != trA[i][j])
        return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

O `if` nesta função retorna 0 (falso) caso um elemento na matriz transposta seja diferente que o o elemento, na posição correspondente, na matriz original. E retorna 1 (verdadeiro) caso todos os elementos da matriz transposta são correspondentes aos elementos na matriz original.

Em sua função `main` basta tratar estes retornos:

```c
int main()
{
  int A[TAM][TAM];

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
    {
      A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
      printf("%3d ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\nMatriz A: \n\n");
  if (ehSimetrica(A))
  {
    printf("A matriz A e uma matriz simetrica\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("A matriz A nao e uma matriz simetrica\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```