# Quais os erros desse código?

Tags: c, syntax-error

Quais os erros desse código em C? O programa está com problema, pois ao digitar as três notas, o valor da média se for abaixo de 7 mostra na tela o status errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
     float p1, p2, p3, media = 0.0;

    printf("Digite a nota 1\n");
     scanf("%f", &p1);
     printf("Digite a nota 2\n");
     scanf("%f", &p2);
     printf("Digite a nota 3\n");
   scanf("%f", &p3);

   media = (p1+p2+p3)/3;
  printf("Média calculada %f\n", media);

   if(media <= 5){
        printf("Reprovado\n");
    }
   if(media <= 7){
         printf("Recuperação\n");
   }
   if(media <= 10){
          printf("Aprovado\n");
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Como assim status errado? O que aparece? Pelo que vi, você precisa dar um `else` nos seus `ifs`, caso contrário os `ifs` `<= 5` e `<= 7` vão ativar juntos (`<= 7`, `<= 5` e `<= 10` também), dependendo do valor da `média`. Sugiro fazer um [Teste de Mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%c3%a9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%c3%a1-lo) usando valores que resultem em uma `média` igual a `5`. OBS: Todos os seus `ifs` serão verificados independente se outro já tiver ativado, para evitar isso use o `else`

Comment: Só complementando https://ideone.com/CzZ8MO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A condição If será executada todas as vezes, imagene da seguinte forma:

Se a nota for menor ou igual a 5, imprima reprovado (Esse está OK)

Se a nota for menor ou igual a 7, imprima Recuperação (Mas um segundo, deveria ter parado no de cima, então tenho que criar uma condição que pare logo no começo, será necessário por um else então)

Se a nota for menor ou igual a 10 aprovado (Vish!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
     float p1, p2, p3, media = 0.0;

    printf("Digite a nota 1\n");
     scanf("%f", &p1);
     printf("Digite a nota 2\n");
     scanf("%f", &p2);
     printf("Digite a nota 3\n");
   scanf("%f", &p3);

   media = (p1+p2+p3)/3;
  printf("Média calculada %f\n", media);

   if(media <= 5){
        printf("Reprovado\n");
    }
   else if(media <= 7){
         printf("Recuperação\n");
   }
   else if(media <= 10){
          printf("Aprovado\n");
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

É recomendado por o else antes de inicializar o próximo if.