# Estou aprendendo a usar funções

Tags: javascript

Estou apenas aprendendo e treinando o uso de funções. Vou tentar explicar qual era o objetivo desse código.

Fiz esse código para criar um verificador de idade. Então eu chamo a função `teste()` crio uma variável b para armazenar a idade digitada. Em seguida b deixa de ser um numero e passa a ser uma string.

o objetivo é criar uma pequena lista para guardar b.

Se alguém puder me dizer se oque fiz de errado eu fico grato.

```
function teste(a){
    b=a
    if(a>=18){
        b=`voce digitou ${b},pode entrar`
    }else{
        b=`voce digitou ${b},não pode entrar`
    }
    incluirNaLista()
}

teste(prompt())   

function incluirNaLista(){
    let lista=[]
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        if(i<5){
            lista[i]=b
            teste(prompt())
        }else{
            lista[i]=b
        }
        console.log(lista[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu código possui uma recursão indireta, o que gera um loop infinito. *Parece*  que você até tentou colocar uma condição de parada baseada no `i` do `for`, mas não adianta, o `for` é irrelevante e o loop seria infinito mesmo sem ele.

Pense bem, toda vez que você chama `teste`, ele chama `incluirNaLista`, que chama `teste`, que chama `incluirNaLista`, e assim por diante... Se não estiver claro, faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%c3%a9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%c3%a1-lo) para entender melhor.

Já que você está estudando funções, é importante entender que elas servem basicamente para evitar repetição de código. E, uma vez que esteja usando funções, é importante que cada uma tenha uma responsabilidade clara, um nome claro, e que haja o mínimo possível de dependências entre elas. Parece simples, mas na verdade é algo que você só aprende mesmo quebrando a cara muitas vezes, na prática, aprendendo passo a passo como não cair em armadilhas que já caiu anteriormente. E, em cada projeto, reescrevendo o código várias vezes.

Também é importante entender que não repetir código (trechos idênticos de código) não significa necessariamente fazer menos operações. Muitas vezes é o contrário disso. Então, no mundo real, é preciso encontrar um equilíbrio entre as duas coisas.

Como esse seu exemplo é bem simples e sem muita utilidade prática, fica difícil sugerir qualquer código. Basicamente, a melhor forma (a mais simples) de fazer essa operação seria sem nenhuma função, pois é uma situação bem simples que você resolve sem repetir código nem operações.