# Erro de index em lista de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, variáveis

O codigo a baixo é uma tentativa de resolver a seguinte questão no the huxley: [3n+1](https://www.thehuxley.com/problem/407?locale=pt_BR)  que consiste em pegar uma sequencia de input, e fazer uma pequena equacao com ela capturando a quantidade de vezes que o numero é processado até chegar em 1 e comparar com uma sequencia de possibilidades.
o problema vem com um função criada, `maxima()` que ignora o index 1 das variaveis parer e impares.

note que a diferença é no resultado da funcao maxima() com index 1, que deveria ser 125 e não 89 (o codigo repete o index 2 duas vezes), a baixo o codigo:

alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
def equacao(n):
    lista = []
    while n != 1:
        lista.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n/2
        else:
            n = (n*3)+1
    else:
        lista.append(n)

    return len(lista)


def maxima(par, impar):
    lista = []
    for index in range(par, impar):
        lista.append(equacao(index))
    return max(lista)


def separarEntrada(numeros):
    pares, impares = [], []
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
        num = int(numeros[i])
        if i % 2 == 0:
            pares.append(num)
        else:
            impares.append(num)
    return pares, impares


def saida(numeros):
    pares, impares = separarEntrada(numeros)
    saida = ""

    for i, j in zip(pares, impares):
        maximo = maxima(i, j)
        saida += str(pares.pop(0)) + " "
        saida += str(impares.pop(0)) + " "
        saida += str(maximo) + '\n'

    return saida


input1 = input("")
input2 = input("")
input3 = input("")
input4 = input("")

# ['1', '10', '100', '200', '201', '210', '900', '1000']
entrada = input1.split() + input2.split() + input3.split() + input4.split()

print(saida(entrada))
```

ao executar com o valor das entradas `['1', '10', '100', '200', '201', '210', '900', '1000']`, o programa ao realizar os calculos, ignora o index 1 das variaveis pares e impares, o que resulta em:

```
1 10 20
100 200 **89**
201 210 89
900 1000 174
```

onde deveria ser :

```
1 10 20
100 200 **125**
201 210 89
900 1000 174
```

Comment: Acho que seria útil você planejar um pouco melhor e descrever seu algoritmo em linguagem comum antes de partir para o código.

Comment: lá na primeira linha tem o link pra questão, mas é esse aqui: https://www.thehuxley.com/problem/407?locale=pt_BR

Comment: Eu li. Estou falando do seu esquema mental para resolver o problema, não do enunciado da questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente sempre simplificar as coisas quando for resolver um problema.

## Gerando a sequência 3n+1

Primeiro, vamos construir uma função (na verdade um gerador) que irá definir a sequência 3n+1 para um determinado inteiro que será o nosso parâmetro:

```py
def sequence(number):
  while number != 1:
    yield number
    number = int(number / 2 if number % 2 == 0 else 3*number + 1)
  yield number
```

> **Nota:** o uso do `int()` é apenas para garantir que a saída seja sempre inteira e simplificar a visualização de valores, visto que com Python a divisão entre inteiros retornaria um float.

Com isso, podemos já testar essa função e validar com algum caso conhecido. Por exemplo, o próprio exercício cita que a sequência para 22 é:

```
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Então ao iterar sobre o nosso gerador para uma entrada igual a 22 devemos obter a mesma saída:

```py
print(list(sequence(22)))
# [22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Exatamente a mesma sequência. Embora funcionar para um caso específico não signifique que funcione para todos, dada a simplicidade do nosso gerador podemos facilmente aferir que ao funcionar para um caso conhecido podemos dizer que a lógica está, de fato, validada. Caso contrário, poderíamos fazer outros [testes de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para garantir o sucesso em diversos cenários.

> **Nota:** como o próprio exercício comenta que todos os valores serão maiores que 0 e menores que 1.000.000 eu não me preocupei em fazer as devidas validações nas funções.

## Calculando o tamanho do ciclo

Basicamente para calcular o tamanho do ciclo para um determinado número, basta contarmos quantas etapas foram necessárias para atingir o valor 1. Em termos práticos, basta contarmos quantos valores serão gerados pelo nosso gerador:

```py
def length(number):
  return len(list(sequence(number)))
```

> **Nota:** para tirarmos mais proveito do fato de ser um gerador, poderíamos aplicar uma solução otimizada utilizando `return sum(1 for _ in sequence(number))`, pois assim evitaríamos ter que armazenar **todos** os valores da sequência em memória, como acontece quando utilizamos o `list`.

Novamente, como o próprio exercício comenta, sabemos que o tamanho do ciclo para o número 22 é 16. Se a nossa lógica estiver correta, o retorno da nossa função deveria ser 16.

```
print(length(22))
# 16
```

## Calculando o tamanho do ciclo em uma faixa

Agora, dados os números `i` e `j` que definem uma faixa de números, podemos calcular o tamanho do ciclo para cada valor. Para isso, podemos novamente definir um gerador que itera os valores da faixa e gera o tamanho do ciclo para cada um deles:

```py
def length_in_range(i, j):
  yield from (length(number) for number in range(i, j+1))
```

Para testar a função bastaria chamar a função `length` para um intervalo conhecido e validar se os valores coincidem com os gerados por `length_in_range`. Dada a simplicidade da função fica muito claro que isso ocorrerá, então para fins de reduzir a resposta, pularei essa etapa.

## Buscando o maior tamanho de ciclo em uma faixa

Para obter o maior tamanho de ciclo em uma faixa basta retornarmos o maior valor gerado por `length_in_range` quando informamos os limites da faixa desejada. Para obter o maior valor de uma sequência podemos utilizar a função nativa `max` do Python:

```py
def max_length_in_range(i, j):
  return max(length_in_range(i, j))
```

E, com isso, basicamente finalizar o exercício, pois para uma faixa definida por 1 e 10, como pede o exercício, teremos o retorno igual a 20:

```
print(max_length_in_range(1, 10))
# 20
```

Você ainda poderia testar todas as possibilidades conhecidas no exercício para certificar-se que está tudo ok:

```py
assert max_length_in_range(1, 10) == 20
assert max_length_in_range(100, 200) == 125
assert max_length_in_range(201, 210) == 89
assert max_length_in_range(900, 1000) == 174
```

Agora basta você tratar as entradas que o exercício fala e calcular o tamanho máximo de ciclo dentro da faixa identificada.