# GetValue() não mostra valor que é atribuída à variavel

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       // ASSIM FUNCIONA
        //var ObjGeneric = new Pessoa();
        //ObjGeneric.Nome = "PAULO TADEU CHAGAS";
        //ObjGeneric.Idade = 25;

         // ASSIM NÃO FUNCIONA 
        //CHAMADA ATRAVÉS DA CLASSE GENERICA NÃO IMPRIME VALOR DA VARIAVEL
        var ObjGeneric = new Generica();
        ObjGeneric.Pessoa.Nome = "PAULO TADEU CHAGAS";
        ObjGeneric.Pessoa.Idade = 25;

        Teste(ObjGeneric);
    }


    static void Teste<T>(T xpto)
    {
        var tipo = xpto.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] propt = tipo.GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in tipo.GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + prop.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Valor: " + prop.GetValue(xpto, null));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

public class Generica
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public Generica()
    {
        this.Pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }
}
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Falta trechos importantes aí para poder testar e ver o erro, e até informações mais precisas sobre o que acontece ou o que quer.

Comment: Coloque a declaração da classe `Generica` na sua pergunta. Sem essa definição só podem ser feitas especulações sobre o comportamento do se código. Especulações do tipo: as propriedades não aparecem na reflexão porque são privadas o protegidas? Ou então: `Nome` e `Valor` não são propriedades, são campos e teriam que ser buscados com `GetFields()`? O ainda: Existe algum metadado modificando suas propriedades de forma  que não possam ser exibidos por reflexão?....

Comment: Segue a definição da classe, ontem não consegui editar a pergunta. Quando eu invoco o método somente usando a classe Pessoa funciona ele imprime o nome e a idade. Agora quando chamo através da classe Generic ele imprime a propriedade nome mas o valor da idade não sai.

Comment: Tem certeza que quer fazer isto? Este código não faz sentido.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Reflexão normalmente é abusada, em raros casos ela é realmente útil e tem um custo grande de performance, e só isto deveria fazer pensar se deve usar, fora o provável problema de robustez. Tem casos para uso, mas se for para economizar digitação não é uma boa ideia, tem opções melhores. Este caso faz coisas desnecessárias.

Não foi fácil entender o que queria porque mesmo tento colocando mais código não deu informações precisas sobre o que deseja (conforme solicitado). Programar é entender o problema em primeiro lugar, a parte fácil é codificar. Quando você não consegue falar para outras pessoas o que deseja é porque nem você sabe muito bem o que deseja e deveria se atentar mais a isso antes de codificar, isto é chamado de técnica do [pato de borracha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210323/101) (isso é bobo, mas a recomendação é boa).

O problema mesmo nem é da reflexão é de passar o que se deseja, está passando um objeto que tem uma propriedade e está imprimindo-a. Como o tipo é por referência o padrão é que o texto dela seja o nome do tipo. Se era isso que queria não tem nada errado. Como está dizendo que queria que imprimisse os valores que está dentro dessa propriedade então deve passar essa propriedade e não o objeto. Então passei `objGeneric.Pessoa`:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var objGeneric = new Generica();
        objGeneric.Pessoa.Nome = "PAULO TADEU CHAGAS";
        objGeneric.Pessoa.Idade = 25;
        Teste(objGeneric.Pessoa);
    }
    static void Teste<T>(T xpto) {
        var tipo = xpto.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propt = tipo.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in tipo.GetProperties()) {
            WriteLine($"Nome: {prop.Name}");
            WriteLine($"Valor: {prop.GetValue(xpto, null)}");
        }
    }
}

public class Generica {
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Generica() => this.Pessoa = new Pessoa();
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RmPfb8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://ideone.com/RmPfb8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/InnerProperty.cs).

Claro, você pode querer que pegue essa propriedade e as propriedades do objeto que estão dentro dela. Mas a pergunta não fala nada sobre isto, então estou dando a solução mais simples possível. Se deseja pegar o que está dentro do objeto também tem que fazer um código que faça isso, provavelmente [recursivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101). Só que tem que tomar cuidado, pode gerar um grafo muito grande e até mesmo cíclico, e sem uma regra clara e implementada para quebrar isso o código irá travar. É extremamente complicado fazer certo e quase sempre é a técnica errada, então não faça.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, esclareceu minha dúvida. Funcionou =)

Comment: @PauloTadeuChagas veja o [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.